# Checkboxes with "return false" and back

Tags: checkbox, preventdefault, clickable

I'd like to create a form with checkboxes. At first it shouldnt be possible to check them. Then if you click submit they should be.

I got it working so its not clickable first with

function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }

But how do i make them clickable again after that?

Answer (score 0):

That means you just want to go the the default behavior what you have removed first time. To this this you just have to do

```
function(e){ return true; }
```

Hope this work.

Comment: yes, it should be default again. unfortunately with return true its not working for me

Comment: then check using unbind function

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to disable the checkbox, then re-enable it when you're ready:

```
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" disabled>

document.getElementById("chk1").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

If you're using jQuery, it would be easier to work with multiple checkboxes, and the syntax would be:

```
jQuery("#chk1").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: that would work, but it should still look the same as an enabled checkbox

Comment: From a user perspective, you're just going to annoy users that way. But if that's your requirement, I'll post another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your click handler to a function, just have that function prevent the click, depending on whether or not you want the boxes enabled. In your case, you said when the submit button was clicked, you want to start allowing them:

```
var _checkBoxesEnabled = false;

function checkBoxClicked(e) {
    if (!_checkBoxesEnabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function submitButtonClicked() {
    _checkBoxesEnabled = true;
}
```

Watch out for cross-browser compatibility - I'm spoiled by jQuery, so I don't remember exactly how the `e` in click handlers work with old IE versions using regular javascript.